# Redmine and SVN integration

Tags: svn, integration, redmine

We use fairly up-to-date Redmine. We use the "# + Redmine number" to reference the Redmine number in the commit message each time after fixing a bug.

I open the Redmine ticket from the browser, no svn information is there. I expect that all the changes or code segments are displayed under that ticket, so I can clearly see which class is changed, and what the changes are.

My question is if this is possible in Redmine, and if yes how?

Answer (score 7):

1. Setup Repository section under Project Settings
2. Setup keywords like `fixes,closes,refs`

After that your related commits will be shown under issue.

Try to read http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories

Comment: plus 1 for adding redmine link.. appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove all keywords and put a single star * into the field. Then you dont need a keyword in the commit message but only #issue like #1234. 
however when you change the keywords the changes are only used for new commits. To get them work for recent commits just remove and readd the repository in the projectsettings

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it might not be so obvious, but I believe that this requires a cron to parse the SVN comments. If you don't setup the cron, it won't show up in the ticket after a commit is done until you actually go to the repository tab and load the svn with the comments. Once this is done, Redmine will have parsed the comments and you should see them in your tickets.

Comment: You are right. There should be something that updates Redmine with the changes in SVN. A shell fired by a cron would do the work. However, a better solution is to hook the shell into SVN 'post-commit'. That ensures SVN and Redmine are instantelly in sync (see http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_setup_automatic_refresh_of_repositories_in_Redmine_on_commit).